# Why is my array claiming to be an object?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a data object whose keys are numbers and values are arrays containing objects. At some point in my code, I'd like to extract the array from that object based on the object key.

The object looks something like this:

```
this.data = {
    1: [{name: "John Doe", occupation: "farmer"}, {name: "Jane Doe", occupation: "teacher"}],
    3: [{name: "Jack Doe", occupation: "plumber"}, {name: "Jean Doe", occupation: "hairdresser"}]
}
```

To extract the arrays, I do something like this...

```
this.people = this.data[1];
```

Now, when I console.log `this.data` it returns `{1: Array(2), 3: Array(2)}`
When I console.log `this.people` it gives me `(2) [{…}, {…}]`

However, `typeof(this.people)` returns `object`. I don't get it.
What's the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because an array is actually an object in javascript (like mostly everything). If you want to check if something is an array object, you can use [**Array.isArray**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

Comment: I know that. The point isn't that I just would like to know the type. I need to be able to loop through the array using `map`, `filter` all that but I can't.

Comment: So you can't `map` or `filter` through your `people` member (which has the value of `this.data[1]`?

Comment: Up until a few mins ago I couldn't but now I can. I think the linter was misbehaving. I can't do this though `private people: Array<Object>;`